# inheritance from non-protocol type 'UIViewController' @objc protocol User: UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

When we declare an optional property to a protocol it needs to be marked with `@objc` attribute.

The protocol is constrained to a class of type `UIViewController`.

```swift
@objc protocol User: UIViewController {
    @objc optional var userImage: UIImage {get set}
}
```

I get the below error. How can I constraint the protocol to the `UIViewController` and have optional property along with it?

```swift
error: inheritance from non-protocol type 'UIViewController'
@objc protocol User: UIViewController {
```

Comment: Something's not right here, how can a `User` be a subclass of a view controller? Did you mean `UserController`?

Comment: It will compile with a warning `Redundant constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'` and when we try to access by the implemented controller, it gives compile time error `Value of type <Implementing Controller>,  has no member "userImage"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricting protocols to certain classes is a Swift-only feature, so the `@objc` declaration here is incompatible with that restriction.

Secondly, you might want to declare you property as an optional (`UIImage?`), as this will match the optionality of the requirement.

If you want optional properties in Swift, then you can add default implementations for them

```swift
protocol User: UIViewController {
    var userImage: UIImage? { get set }
}

extension UIViewController {
    var userImage: UIImage? { 
        get { nil } 
        set { /* do nothing */ }
}
```

However this will make your class conformers non-objc, thus you won't be able to use them from Objective-C.

Comment: Good point on the restrictions applicable only to Swift and as such it's not available for objective-c. I preferred to use the second point i.e declare it as optional `UIImage?`